# Maximum distance between a Point and a LineString

Tags: python, performance, distance, shapely

The [`distance`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.distance) method in Shapely returns the *minimum* distance between two geometric objects. There is no method which returns the *maximum* distance. But there is a [`hausdorff_distance`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.hausdorff_distance) method which returns ... well:

> Returns the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) (*float*) to the *other* geometric object. The Hausdorff distance between two geometries is the furthest distance that a point on either geometry can be from the nearest point to it on the other geometry.

The Hausdorff Distance between a single Point and a LineString actually *is* the maximum distance between the two.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

ls = LineString(pt for pt in zip(range(1000), [0]*1000))  # [(0, 0), (1, 0), ..., (999, 0)]
pt = Point((-1, 0))

pt.hausdorff_distance(ls)  # 1000.0
```

But this is **slow(er).**

```
for i in range(10000):
    pt.hausdorff_distance(ls)
# 3.76 s

for i in range(10000):
    pt.distance(ls)
# 0.550 s
```

Why is calculating the *maximum* distance between a Point and a LineString is 7x slower than the *minimum* distance? I have a strong intuition that the best implementation of both calculations would run in about equal time. Is there another library in Python which I can use to calculate this faster? Or perhaps an algorithm which I can implement myself?

Comment: Did you try looking at how each calculation is implemented in shapely? That would either confirm or disprove your belief about their relative performance.

Comment: The difference in performance is probably because the `distance` is calculated [analytically](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/master/src/algorithm/Distance.cpp#L30-L79), and `hausdorff_distance` calculates an [approximation by discretizing](http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1algorithm_1_1distance_1_1DiscreteHausdorffDistance.html) the input geometries. As an alternative, I was going to propose calculating `distance` for each point in the `LineString` and taking the max, but after testing it locally I see that it will be too slow for strings of thousands points.

Comment: Looking over the `Point` to `LineSegment` calculation @Georgy provided and the [`Point` to `LineString`](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/master/src/algorithm/Distance.cpp#L178-L201) distance calculation lower in the file, the calculation for *maximum* distance should actually be much faster than for minimum distance because the maximum distance will always be at a vertex of the `LineString`.